# How to read the content from Nutch index?

Tags: lucene, nutch

I can crawl and index the web pages using *Nutch*, but I don't know how to read the index and extract data from it.

Could anyone introduce to me some useful tools to read the index?

I want to add a *Chinese Language Analyzer* and a `IndexFilter` plugin, so I want to read the index to validate my plugin. And also, I want to do some process with the data I crawled using Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [luke tool](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) to browse the nutch indexes. The dump index option can create an xml file for entire index. If you have to do it via code, then you need to learn lucene.

To read the crawled content, use the [nutch segment reader](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/nutch-0.8-dev/bin/nutch_segread).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the provided read command like

```
bin/nutch readseg xxx
```

to read the content.

Hope [this](http://arifn.web.id/blog/2010/11/29/simple-crawling-with-nutch.html) will help you.

Comment: Hi John, very glad to communicate with you. I can not find your email in the profile page.(actually, I'm new here). Please mail me(lilintao1989@gmail.com). I'm looking forward to your email. <br>best.